# Customize "cd" in bash

Tags: bash, alias, cd

I just think that it is convenient for me to "cd" to the directory where I store some file, ie.

```
[admin@local /]$ cd /usr/bin/somefile.pl
```

which as far as I know that the official "cd" command will not work.

so I wrote something like this:

```
main () {
    if [[ "${1}" =~ "(.+/)*(.*){1}" ]] && [ -f "${1}" ] ; then
            `\cd ${1%/*}`
    elif [ -f "${1}" ] ; then
            exit 0
    else ; `\cd ${1}`
    fi
}
main ${1}
```

and I alias this cd.sh to the "cd" command:

```
alias cd='source /somepath/cd.sh'
```

and this doesn't work.

I've tried to use `eval "\cd xxx"` instead of just `\cd xxx`;

How can I fix my script?

Comment: Dude, this is a sweet idea. But please, use `basename` to manipulate paths, not regular expressions.

Comment: because sometime i just want to see what files are storing with the file i'm looking at lol, when i know the abs path of that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It feels like a bad idea to override `cd`, so I'll suggest a slightly different command, `fcd`:

```
fcd() { cd -- "$(dirname -- "$1")"; }

$ fcd /usr/bin/somefile.pl
$ pwd
/usr/bin
```

Or using parameter expansion to save a call to `dirname`:

```
fcd { cd -- "${1%/*}"; }
```

Comment: He actually didn't redefined `cd`

Comment: +1: need some extra quotes `fcd() { cd "$(dirname "$1")"; }` in case the directory name contains spaces.

Comment: @user990106 actually, dirname isn't ideal either -- using it in this way requires forking off a subshell, and reading and parsing its stdout. The parameter expansion version you gave in your original version, `${1%/*}`, is more efficient.

Comment: actually you need cd `"$(dirname -- "$1")"` in case `$1` starts with `-` -- try `fcd --help`

Comment: Bash is never simple, is it? :) I've included andrew's suggestion to handle arguments that start with "-", and added Charles' suggestion to use parameter expansion in place of process subsitution.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd() {
    DN="$(dirname "$1")"
    if [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
        builtin cd "$1"
    elif [[ -d "$DN" ]]; then
        builtin cd "$DN"
    else
        echo "$* or $DN: No such directories"
        return 1
    fi
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Why the `"$*"`? Is there _any_ case where taking multiple command-line arguments and smooshing them together into one with the first character of `$IFS` interspersed is going to be the right behavior?

Comment: Also, consider replacing the `"$(dirname "$foo")"` call with parameter expansion, ie. `"${foo%/*}"` -- this requires no subshell and will thus perform far better.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the real `cd` considers all its parameters as one, so who cares. If you try `cd one two` (without quotes) `cd` will try to cd to the dir `one two` (with a space)

Comment: @KerzedMetal not on bash 4.2.10, it doesn't.

Comment: @KerzedMetal ...also, pay attention to the case of `cd one   two`; a builtin, being syntax, can get to the actual literal command entered, and determine the number of spaces; a function can't, and couldn't distinguish between `one   two` and `one two`. As such, allowing folks to use cd without quoting their argument list is just going to lead to confusion whenever multiple elements of IFS are found next to each other or an element of IFS rather than the first one is used.